# Android React Native Module already registered

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to develop custom native toast component for android using below document. after deploying build i am getting following exception. Please help me to resolve this.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Module ToastAndroid was already registered!
10-15 18:06:20.576 6947-6947/com.helloworldbha E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.infer.annotation.Assertions.assertCondition(Assertions.java:65)
10-15 18:06:20.576 6947-6947/com.helloworldbha E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry$Builder.add(NativeModuleRegistry.java:162)
10-15 18:06:20.576 6947-6947/com.helloworldbha E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.processPackage(ReactInstanceManager.java:447)
10-15 18:06:20.576 6947-6947/com.helloworldbha E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:416)
10-15 18:06:20.576 6947-6947/com.helloworldbha E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:345)
10-15 18:06:20.576 6947-6947/com.helloworldbha E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.onJSBundleLoadedFromServer(ReactInstanceManager.java:310)
10-15 18:06:20.576 6947-6947/com.helloworldbha E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$100(ReactInstanceManager.java:70)
10-15 18:06:20.576 6947-6947/com.helloworldbha E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$1.onJSBundleLoadedFromServer(ReactInstanceManager.java:97)
10-15 18:06:20.576 6947-6947/com.helloworldbha E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManager$13$1.run(DevSupportManager.java:530)
10-15 18:06:20.576 6947-6947/com.helloworldbha E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-15 18:06:20.576 6947-6947/com.helloworldbha E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-15 18:06:20.576 6947-6947/com.helloworldbha E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-15 18:06:20.576 6947-6947/com.helloworldbha E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
10-15 18:06:20.576 6947-6947/com.helloworldbha E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-15 18:06:20.576 6947-6947/com.helloworldbha E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-15 18:06:20.576 6947-6947/com.helloworldbha E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
10-15 18:06:20.576 6947-6947/com.helloworldbha E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Maybe you could add a code example, as to where you think the error might be happening or just an omitted version of the code so we can have an idea of how to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

your module could not name ‘ ToastAndroid’ ，cause the core package already have  a  module with that name .

see '[com.facebook.react.modules.toast.ToastModule](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/toast/ToastModule.java)'.

so change your module's name will fix it.

Comment: Hi i already did but failed :(  . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33145554/react-native-required-unknown-module-for-custom-native-component